# Get fetchall result from different class

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo, fetchall

let me explain what i'm trying to do.

In one **DBcommand.php** file i have :

```
class DBcommand Extends PdoDB { 
     public function selectAll() {
       $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT hwid,username,pcname FROM users");
       $stmt->execute();
       $columnn = array();
       $result_returned = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
       foreach($result_returned as $key=>$result) {
         $columnn['hwid'] = $result->hwid;
         $columnn['username'] = $result->username;
         $columnn['pcname'] = $result->pcname;
         //return $columnn;
         //$columnn= new us($result->hwid,$result->username,$result->pcname);
       }
       return $columnn;
     }
}
```

And i'm trying to get my result on another page called **View.php**

```
$cmd = new DBcommand();
//$get = $cmd->getInfo('1234');
$result=$cmd->selectAll();

echo '<tr ><td ><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td><td>' . $result['hwid'] . '</td><td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="alert(\'ok\')">' . $result['username'] . '</td><td style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="alert(\'ok\')">' . $result['pcname']. '</td><td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" onclick="myAjax()"></span></button></p></td>
  <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></td>
</tr>';
                                        ?>
```

The issue i have is , my selectall works , but my view.php only get 1 info from it, either the first one or last one.

Even if i try to make some kind of while on the view.php part, it never get all result.

lets say my selectAll return **array('123','azerty',azerty');** and **array('6547','qwertty',qwerty');**  , my **print_r** from selectAll will show me what i want to see, but my result from view.php, will only show me one of these 2 result.

--

I even tried to create another class that takes $this->_hwid, so i'll use this class later, but didnt manage, since its object in string result.

--

Getting stuck, Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're overwriting values in your `foreach` loop. And why are you injecting an object of `PdoDB` in `DBcommand` you're alreading extending it.

Comment: Yes thanks i corrected the DB thing, it was due to an old test. Yes in this exemple, i am overwritting, but even if i put the return inside the foreach, result remind the same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your foreach always fills just one item in the array.

try this instead:

```
 foreach($result_returned as $key=>$result) {
   $columnn[$key]['hwid'] = $result->hwid;
   $columnn[$key]['username'] = $result->username;
   $columnn[$key]['pcname'] = $result->pcname;
 }
```

Comment: How do i get result from this on the view.php side?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function selectAll() {
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT hwid,username,pcname FROM users");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

this is ALL the code for the problem function you need.

your other code also requires minimal understanding of a technology you are using. At least you have to realize that you're getting multiple rows from the table, in the form of array, which usually being looped over using `foreach()` command.